# Is there a simpler way to enforce length > 0 when deserialising an array?

Tags: kotlin, jackson2, jackson-databind

Let's say I receive some JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "class": "TimesContainer",
    "times": ["08:00", "09:15", "12:30"]
}
```

There may be some other fields, but I'm simplifying for this question. I would like to deserialise this JSON into an object of the following class:

```
class TimesContainer(
    @JsonProperty("times")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "HH:mm")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalTimeListDeserializer::class)
    val timesOfDay: List<LocalTime>
) {
    //Other code here
}
```

My requirements are that the timesOfDay list is sorted, using LocalTime's natural ordering, and that the list is not empty.

So far, I have a custom deserializer, specifically for lists of LocalTime:

```
   class LocalTimeListDeserializer(private val formatter: DateTimeFormatter? = null)
    : StdDeserializer<List<LocalTime>>(List::class.java), ContextualDeserializer {

    @Throws(JsonMappingException::class)
    override fun createContextual(context: DeserializationContext, property: BeanProperty): JsonDeserializer<*> {
        val format: JsonFormat.Value? = findFormatOverrides(context, property, handledType())
        if (format != null) {
            if (format.hasPattern()) {
                val pattern = format.pattern
                return LocalTimeListDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern))
            }
        }
        return this
    }

    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): List<LocalTime>? {
        val formatter = this.formatter ?: DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME

        if (parser.currentTokenId == JsonTokenId.ID_START_ARRAY) {
            val list: MutableList<LocalTime> = mutableListOf()
            while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY)  {
                if (parser.currentToken == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
                    try {
                        list.add(LocalTime.parse(parser.valueAsString, formatter))
                    } catch (dtpe: DateTimeParseException) {
                        throw context.weirdStringException(parser.valueAsString, LocalTime::class.java, dtpe.message).initCause(dtpe)
                    }
                } else {
                    throw context.wrongTokenException(parser, LocalTime::class.java, JsonToken.VALUE_STRING, "Invalid time of day")
                }
            }

            if (list.isEmpty()) {
                throw context.reportInputMismatch(List::class.java, "TimesContainer requires at least one time of day")
            }

            return list.sorted()
        } else {
            throw context.wrongTokenException(parser, List::class.java, JsonToken.START_ARRAY, "Invalid list of times of day")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a simpler way to enforce the list being non-empty. I am okay with sorting the list in TimesContainer's constructor.

In a previous attempt, I raised an exception in TimesContainer's constructor, however this resulted in an InvalidDefinitionException, which implies there is something wrong with the class definition. I therefore think this is not the right way to go, as the class definition is correct.

I also considered validating the list separately after deserialising, but I realised this would mean I am no longer leveraging Jackson to inform the user precisely where their JSON was wrong.

I am using the following libraries so far:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+
- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.+

I have examined https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations and https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Databind-Annotations to try to find an annotation that might help with this, but I am stumped.